# Sum within group for smaller than current value in R

Tags: r, dplyr, sum, group

I have the following dataframe and would like to calculate the sum of column "toSum" for all rows within the group ("id") for which another column ("index") has smaller values than the current row.

```
id <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B")
index <- c(5,7,11,2,5,8)
toSum <- c(0.5,0.4,0.2,0.1,0.9,0.8) 
data <- data.frame(id, index, toSum)
```

| id | index | toSum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5 | 0.5 |
| A | 7 | 0.4 |
| A | 11 | 0.2 |
| B | 2 | 0.1 |
| B | 5 | 0.9 |
| B | 8 | 0.8 |

I would like to add the results as a column like this:

| id | index | toSum | priorSum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5 | 0.5 | 0 |
| A | 7 | 0.4 | 0.5 |
| A | 11 | 0.2 | 0.9 |
| B | 2 | 0.1 | 0 |
| B | 5 | 0.9 | 0.1 |
| B | 8 | 0.8 | 1 |

I am able to calculate the number of rows within the group for which the value is lower with this code:     `data <- data %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(priorSum = map_int(index, ~ sum(.x > index)))`

However, I cannot sum over a different variable.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: What about `mutate(priorSum = cumsum(lag(toSum, default = 0)))`?

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Maël. That definitely works for sorted data. Do you also know a solution for data that is not necessarily sorted by "index"?

Comment: Well, maybe you could sort it beforehand? using `arrange` in dplyr.

Comment: Yes, I sorted it and it worked perfectly. I was just curious, thank you!

Comment: How about using `tapply()` and `cumsum()`?